# New Method for a Passive Magnetic Bearing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, electromagnetism, bearings, magnets

Is it possible to create a passive magnetic bearing by layering the outside of a shaft with a magnetic film and placing a magnetic ring on the outside. The outer layer of the film would have a north pole while the inner layer of the ring would also have a north pole (schematic below). I understand the ring would fall down due to its weight, but in the radial direction, would the system be stable?

Theoretically, it seems plausible, but I wasn't able to find any papers detailing the associated equation for force.

[image: Magnetic Ring around a Shaft Covered in Magnetic Film]

Thank you.

Comment: Consider the interactions between the N and where their S would have to be.  Draw lines from N to S, away from N.  Because of how unstable it ends up (like balancing a ball on a ball), there is a need for something else to handle any slight changes in load.  Closest visually would be something that uses the undesired motion to generate a magnetic field to induce a load toward the desired stable state, usually via sapping something's velocity - just a mechanical version of an active version that might use sensors and a battery.